# Laravel 5 controller can't make a Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I used `php artisan Tinker` on the command line as well as using my local server to try to make a query but I get the same error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'where' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Code in question:

```
$project = new Project::where('id',1);
```

What am I doing wrong? I can create and read a record just fine but I can't query with a where clause or anything of it.

Comment: Isn't `Project` namespaced ?

Comment: We need to see more code.

Comment: @gmsantos, Project is namespaced. 

use App\Project;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to add the keyword `new` here as it is a static call.

First ensure you have it referenced using `use Project`

Next if you want `$project` to contain the model you will need to call `first();`

So result would be

```
$project = Project::where('id',1)->first();
```

Also as reminded by [@darthmaim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193252/darthmaim) you can use

```
Project::find(1);
```

which is shorthand for above.

See [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) for docs

Comment: You could also use `Project::find(1)`.

Comment: @darthmaim Updated my answer. I use it everyday and still manage to forget it! thanks

Comment: @AbstractChaos are you sure it is static call?

Comment: @ezpura yes i'm pretty sure, it follows normal php [syntax for static](http://php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call.php)

Comment: @AbstractChaos i am not sure but check this http://usman.it/laravel-4-uses-static-not-true/

Comment: @ezpura ok yes, it uses Dependency Injection to resolve and instantiate the class, to the user of the framework it appears to be a static method call, even if under the hood its calling  __callStatic and resolving that to a method in it's instance. But the question is does knowing that extra informaton help solve the OP's question?